# Is this formula correct for $n(A\cup B') $?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

I am trying to identify a formula for $n(A \cup B') $ where $B'$ is the complement of $B$. What I did was the following: 
$$\begin{align} 
n(A \cup B')&= n((A'B)')\\
&= n((B-AB)')\\
&= n(U-(B-AB))\\
&= n(U) - n(B) + n(AB)
\end{align}$$
giving 
$$ n(A \cup B') = n(U) - n(B) + n(AB)$$ 
noting that $AB = A \cap B $

And I am just wondering if this is the correct form ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is correct, except in your final line you wrote an "=" instead of a "-".

And I would use = instead of $\implies$ in your derivation.